# How to fix Django "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'" on AWS ElasticBeanstalk?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I faced this issue as well. In my case I was getting a 502 nginx error after deploying to AWS EB using eb deploy and my environment had a red flag. My AWS EB was using Amazon Linux. my verion of django is 4.1.3, python version is 3.9 (also tried with 3.11).

```
option_settings:
 aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
  WSGIPath: gnt.wsgi:application
```

project dir.

-root-folder
-apps
-requirements.txt
-.ebextensions
-django.config
-gnt
-wsgi.py
-settings.py